# Kendo UI: Unable to bind ViewModel to body or main container div

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm having a page, which comprises of a splitter, a grid, a form and an autocomplete.

For now I have created a view model and binding it to a Grid... The data gets bound successfully:-

```
kendo.bind($("#grid"), viewModel); //**Runs well**
```

However,

```
kendo.bind(document.body, viewModel); // **This doesn't**
```

When I try binding the view model to the body or the main container div (wrapper), the Grid disappears from the page and so do some other fields..

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is that I want to pass an Object (grid row details) from one view model to another view model (i.e. the form). So rather than doing, that I thought of binding the complete view model to the Body...

Could you please let me know where am I going wrong?

Thanks!!

Hardik

Comment: We can't tell you anything until you show us the complete page. Ideally a jsbin or jsfiddle example.

Comment: Yes...Will jus prepare a sample and upload it there... Thanks for the feedback!! :)

Comment: Well...its funny... I am able to bind the view model to body in the JSBin but not on my page..However, http://jsbin.com/ezonev/7/edit is the sample which I have created which has 2 view models the grid and the form.. how shall i pass the current record details to the second view model??

Comment: Hii All, I could finally resolve this by creating a template of the form, which would get updated automatically on selection of the Grid Row...Thanks for replying to my question!!

Comment: However, Just one question.. On the dataBound event of the grid, how shall I keep the first row selected by default when page loads??

Comment: Got that as well..... var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");console.log(grid.dataItem("tr:eq(1)"));

Comment: Got to learn one thing.. that we need to provide array of objects to the template and not directly the object...

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax to bind view model of grid

**kendo.bind(document.body.children, viewModel);**